# When creating a timer.SImple it gives me bad argument #2 error

Tags: timer, lua

When I try to create a timer.Simple in my code I am given this error:

```
bad argument #2 to 'Simple' (function expected, got no value)
```

I have looked for many different places to fine the answer but couldnt find anything to fix this.
the code:

```
http.Fetch( "http://api.time-gaming.co.uk/lua-api.php?key="..ipsd.key.."&email="..ipsd.email.."&type=info",
function( body, len, headers, code )
    ipsd.initaldata = body
    print("Checking Licence Key!")
    print(ipsd.initaldata)
    timer.Simple( 2, activate() )
 end,
 function( error )
    print("Failed to recive data from the web!")
 end
)
```

Comment: Try `timer.Simple( 2, activate )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on EgorSkriptunoff's suggestion in the comments: you are passing the *result* of the `activate` call to `timer.Simple` (which probably doesn't return anything), but you want instead to pass the actual function as this is what will be called by the timer when it expires.

Using `timer.Simple(2, activate)` should produce the result you want.